# Price attribute not showing in admin panel in magento2

Tags: price, magento2.3.2

Product prices are shown in admin product grid correctly.
[image]

But, if I click on Edit button to edit the product, the price attribute is not shown there!
[image]

I have checked the price attribute and it is showing visible as No,
[image]

I am not sure if this is the reason or anything else. I also could not find any way to update those values after opening the attribute in admin.
Please let me know how I can view product prices to edit them from backend Admin.

Comment: Have you checked the log files whether any error is generated or not?

Comment: The attribute's visible = Yes is needed, if you want to include the attribute on the Additional Information tab of the product page. So, this is not the reason, perhaps it generates error anywhere!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this sql query then your price will be visible on admin. Change 75 according to your price attribute id.

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET apply_to = "simple,virtual,downloadable,configurable,grouped,bundle" WHERE attribute_id=75;
```